# I'm having a lot of trouble organising these if statements in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, statements

I have to do a recommend-a-laptop project for school, and I want to keep it as concise as possible by using very long if statements with multiple conditions.
I have many of these, but here's one of them:

```
if 
      ((questionArray [0].equals ("A") && (questionArray [1].equals ("A") || ("B") || ("C") || ("D")) && questionArray [2].equals ("A") && questionArray [3].equals ("A") && questionArray [4].equals ("A") || ("B") || ("C") || ("D")) 
{


System.out.println("ASUS Laptop E200HA-UB02-GD 11.6 inch");

}
```

I am constantly getting, Error: '(' expected and I can't seem to figure it out. Please help!

Comment: to put it simply, you can't do this --> ("A") || ("B") || ("C") || ("D")) ;

Comment: Correction, these are the errors I'm getting: Error: bad operand types for binary operator '||'
  first type:  boolean
  second type: java.lang.String

Comment: After `||` , you need to write `questionArray [4].equals("B")...`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help everyone, it worked! :)

Comment: "I want to keep it as concise as possible by using very long if statements with multiple conditions" --- This is making your life harder, not easier.  (For example, you've got an extra `(` hiding in that mess of a conditional.)  Write a separate method for each attribute you're querying, or at least a separate `if` statement.

Comment: Also, if you intend those "A or B or C or D" conditionals to mean "any response is OK", you can simply remove them --- there's no need to test `questionArray[1]` or `questionArray[4]` at all if _all_ values pass the test.  (If there are 5 or more possible values, this won't work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `||` , you need to write `questionArray [4].equals("B")...`

The complete code

```
 if ((questionArray[0].equals("A")) && (questionArray[1].equals("A"))
                || (questionArray[1].equals("B")) || (questionArray[1].equals("C"))
                || (questionArray[1].equals("D")) && (questionArray[2].equals("A"))
                && (questionArray[3].equals("A")) && (questionArray[4].equals("A"))
                || (questionArray[4].equals("B")) || (questionArray[4].equals("C"))
                || (questionArray.equals("D"))) 
  {

      System.out.println("ASUS Laptop E200HA-UB02-GD 11.6 inch");
   }
```

The error gone now but I'm not sure whether this code wii work since I never tried mixing the `||` operator with the `&&` operator.